# Remove last item in array of optional images

Tags: arrays, swift, option-type

So I have an array: `var pics:[UIImage?] = []`

when I type: `pics.removeLast()`

XCode returns me the yellow triangle with error `"Expression of type 'UIImage?' is unused"`

How to remove the last item without errors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the method declaration removeLast() returns an Iterator.Element. To silent the warning you can use _.

Example: _ = pics.removeLast()